# Différence entre nom complet et nom partiel

Tags: noms-propres

Je suis en train de comprendre la différence entre un **nom complet** et son **nom partiel**. Il peut être un nom propre, commun etc.

J'ai formulé cette définition:

> Le nom complet est le groupe de mots le plus complet permettant de le
>   désigner. Son nom partiel, qui peut être plus court, est le nom le
>   plus usuel permettant de le désigner. Par exemple :
>
> « Angela Dorothea Merkel, née Kasner » pour « Angela Merkel »
>   « William Jefferson Clinton, né William Jefferson Blighte III » pour
>   « Bill Clinton »

Est ce que la définition est correcte?

Comment: Je vois que pour Angela vous ne mettez que son ‘nom [de famille] de jeune fille’ (Kasner) suivant ‘née,’ mais pour Bilou vous mettez son ‘nom de naissance’ complet après ‘né’ (même si ses deux prénoms n’ont pas été changés). Pour être ‘complètement complet’ (sans parlant d’être complètement égale entre ces 2 personnages), je mettrais «Angela Dorothea Merkel, née Angela Dorothea Kasner» pour Angela. (ou, [partially in jest] «Angela Dorothea Kasner, épouse Merkel» pour Angela; et “William Jefferson Clinton, né Blight III, époux  Hillary” pour Bilou.)

Comment: Merci, @cl-r, mais je voulais seulement exprimer mon opinion que les 2 noms/2 sexes doivent etre traitees egalement, sans sachant du tout l'ordre correcte (et aussi pour pas louper l'occassion de parler de Bill comme "epoux de Hillary"!). Je suis d'accord que l'info dont vous parlez doit etre dans une reponse, mais, s'il vous plait, faites cela vous-meme pour Hani dans une forme plus serieuse que la mienne (et surtout avec plus de "lisibilitee" que j'en serais capable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pour bien comprendre, j'ai trouvé le certificat de naissance de [Céline Dion](http://www.celinedionweb.com/images/event/1968/celine-dion-s-birth-certificate_19680330ncd010.jpg).

Son nom complet serait les trois prénoms suivi de son nom. Son nom partiel, celui connu de tout le monde est évidemment Céline Dion. Sur ses autres papiers (carte d'assurance maladie, passeport) il est écrit Céline Dion.

Comment: est ce ma définition est correcte? je peux m'en servir pour définir les nom complets?

Comment: Oui elle est bonne

Comment: Elle est excellente mais elle ne correspond pas du tout à l'usage. L'administration française semble avoir une définition du nom complet qui correspond beaucoup plus à la définition donnée par cl-r.

Answer (score 2):

***Le nom partiel***

On commence toujours par le prénom, sans civilité :

- Brigitte Bardot.
- Valérie Giscard d'Estaing (abrégé en VGE).

Si le nom est porté par une seule personne très connue, le nom suffit :

- Aznavour  (pour Charles A.)
- Céline (pour Louis-Ferdinand C.)

Il y a des noms connus, mais qui référencent des personnes différentes, voire des sociétés, par exemple : Camus, dans un contexte de littérature il s'agit d'Albert C., sinon il faut préciser qu'il s'agit d'une entreprise : Cognac Camus.

***Le nom complet***

- *Monsieur ou Madame* (Par une décision du 26 décembre 2012, Mademoiselle est supprimé des formulaires administratifs)
- *Nom* : nom déclaré à l'état civil au moment de la naissance ; depuis 2005, un enfant peut accoler les noms de ses deux parents, et les époux peuvent faire inscrire leurs deux noms sur les papiers officiels.
- *Prénom**s*** - Tous les prénoms : il était d'usage, dans les deux premiers tiers du XX<sup>e</sup> siècle de donner trois prénoms à un enfant.

***Pour les femmes mariées***

Les impôts :

- *Nom de jeune fille*,
- *Prénom usuel* + [*Prénoms secondaires* s'il s'agit d'une identification complète (première fois que la personne est nommée dans le texte)],
- **épouse** *Nom marital*.

Cette personne sera appelée couramment *Madame PrénomUsuel NomMarital*.

Certains actes inversent la formule :

*Madame PrénomUsuel [Prénoms secondaires pour la première citation dans le texte] NomMarital* **née** *NomDeJeuneFille* **ci-après** *Madame [on ajoute le prénom usuel s'il y a plusieurs femme du même nom] NomMarital* (on indique ici le nom partiel qui sera utilisé ensuite dans le texte).

***Identification officielle complète***

Quel que soit l'ordre de présentation, une personne est reconnue unique par l’État français si dans son état civil est mentionné :

- son nom (celui de l'acte de naissance)
- son ou ses prénoms
- sa situation de famille éventuelle (épouse/époux)
- son lieu de naissance
- sa date de naissance

pour éviter toute homonymie possible.

Comment: Très bien (et merci bcp), mais il faut faire gaffe des fois en parlant à travers les générations d’un connu : « Brel ? Ouais, pas mal lui, mais tu veux dire ‘Cabrel‘ ou plutôt ‘Bruel ‘, non, pépé » ?

Comment: @PapaPoule - VGE ne dépare pas  la photo "Merkel - Clinton". Certaines autres questions du site tournent actuellement autour de l'Étranger de Camus, pour ceux qui s’intéressent à la littérature française, Céline est incontournable (j'ai aussi pensé à Stendhal... peut-être plus connu de certains, mais il n'a pas eu l'influence de Céline sur l'écriture contemporaine). Quant à Bardot, ses bébés phoques ensanglantés ont fait le tour du monde, et Aznavour chantent en anglais et dans beaucoup d'autres langues ! :)